# rJava on macOS with M1X processor

Tags: r, rjava, macos-monterey

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to install and use the *rJava* package in R when having the following configuration:

- MacBookPro with M1X processor,
- macOs 12.1 Monterrey,
- Java11, build Azul Zulu 11.0.13+8
- R 4.1.2?

After installation from CRAN, an attempt to load rJava results in the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/libjli.dylib' (no such file)
```

Thank you very much for your help!
Tomek

Answer (score 1):

You are running Intel R on M1 machine in emulation.

Install native arm64 R instead (the [R-4.1.2-arm64.pkg](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/base/R-4.1.2-arm64.pkg) download from CRAN).